# hide a certain item and remove the left empty line

Tags: lists, description

Is there a way to define a new command `\noitem` where its contents are hidden, in the same way I put in MWE?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand[2]{\noitem}{\item[]{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}} % better define this

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[test 1] this line is to appear
  \noitem[test 2] this line is to be empty
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I want to be able use two types of constructions inside a description environment: `\noitem` and `\item`. The `\item` is the regular as we all know. The `\noitem` simple hides the text inside the list, without leaving extra line or so. The purpose of `\noitem` is somehow similar to the use of `%` when you want to hide a part of your code. Moreover, I want to be able to use it elsewhere in the environment: in the beginning, in the middle, or at the end. The position inside the environment will be unknown to me, because this is to run inside other command.

The question is how to properly define the `\noitem` command to be used inside description, removing the extra line that `\item[]{}` leaves?

Comment: This looks a bit like an [XY Problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean). Could you elaborate a bit more on what you try to reach with this construct?

Comment: If it;s not the last you could use `\long\def\noitem#1\item{}` If it is the last you could use `\long\def\lastnoitem#1\end#2{}` so long as there are no nested environments

Comment: Ok. Let's elaborate a bit more. I want to be able use two types of constructions inside a `description` environment: `\noitem` and `\item`. The `\item` is the regular as we all know. The `\noitem` simple hides the text inside the list, without leaving extra line or so. The purpose of `\noitem` is somehow similar to the use of `%` when you want to hide a part of your code. Moreover, I want to be able to use it elsewhere in the environment: in the beginning, in the middle, or at the end. The position inside the environment will be unknown to me, because this is to run inside other command.

Comment: If you put the whole data field in braces   \noitem[test 2] {this line is to be empty}, then you could define \newcommand\noitem[2][]{}, I think, and blot it out.  Don't know if those extra braces are acceptable to you?

Comment: It may have extra brackets, no problem with that. But it also to run inside `description` environment, that is why I put `\item` in the definition of `\noitem`.

Comment: I edited your question to add the explanation you gave in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work, but only for first level `description` environment: don't nest them if there's a `\noitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\noitem#1\end{\noitemaux#1\item\end}
\makeatletter
\long\def\noitemaux#1\item#2\end{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\end}
  {\remove@item #2\@nil\end}%
}
\long\def\remove@item#1\item\@nil{\item #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \noitem[test 0] this line is to be empty
  \item[test 1] this line is to appear
  \item[test 2] this line is to appear
  \noitem[test 3] this line is to be empty
  \noitem[test 4] this line is to be empty
  \item[test 5] this line is to appear
  \noitem[test 6] this line is to be empty
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is a first approach. However, I tried to use `\noitem` with empty arguments `\noitem[]{}` and/or when it is the first element in the list, but it didn't work out.

Comment: @cacamailg The bug should be fixed

Comment: Your answer is ok. However, know I am trying to use it inside a `\expandafter\ifx ... \else \noitem[]{} \fi` but it is giving me an error `\end occurred when \ifx on line 48 was incomplete`. I tried to replace `\noitem[]{}`, with `\item[]{}` and it compiles without the error. Any idea?

Comment: You have to get rid of the `\fi` before `\noitem` is expanded. It has nothing to do with this question and probably is good for a follow-up. But I can't understand *why* you want to insert a `\noitem[]{}` in the first place, as it should do nothing at all! Just don't add it!

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work in the particular case where I want to hide all the contents of the environment, because it requires at least one `\item`.

Comment: @cacamailg Of course a `description` with nothing in it will raise an error, but this has nothing to do with these macros.