# Suppress output for a group

Tags: macros, tex-core

I have an `\item` style command where I need to be able to suppress output for the following text. I can do this with `\nullfont`, but that seems like a poor hack. Is there a declaration that will suppress all output, along the lines of an `\sbox0` but that is a declaration and not a command?

Here's a minimal working example (the real `\myitem` and the context in which it is used are more complicated).

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
  \nullfont% <-- want a better way to do this
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[foo] show this
    \myitem{bar} suppress this
    \item[foobar] show this too
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that this is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97347/selectively-suppress-generation-of-typeset-output) but I can't modify the original tex source and thus don't have a handler for the end of the text associated with the item. There aren't paragraph skips between items.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100995/hide-a-certain-item-and-remove-the-left-empty-line The solution given there for `description` works also for `enumerate` (first level only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you don't have multiple paragraph entries you can use `\par` to end the item:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\def\myitem{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\def\par{\endgraf\egroup\par}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[foo] show this
    \myitem{bar} suppress this
    \item[foobar] show this too
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, this is basically working. What's causing the enumeration formatting problem for the `foobar` item?

Comment: @Luke sorry change final `\endgraf` to `\par` as in updated answer.

Comment: Ahh, I understand this completely now. Thanks David.