# Hide second enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I would like to be able to hide various `\item` commands. Right now I have something working`like this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{Aufgabea}
\setboolean{Aufgabea}{true}
\newboolean{Aufgabeb}
\setboolean{Aufgabeb}{true}

\ifAufgabea
\long\def\itema#1\end{\itemaaux#1\item\end}
\makeatletter
\long\def\itemaaux#1\item#2\end{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\end}
{\remove@item #2\@nil\end}%
}
\long\def\remove@item#1\item\@nil{\item #1}
\makeatother
\else
%\long\def\itema#1\end{\item#1}
\newcommand{\itema}{\item}
\fi




\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \itema hide if boolean is true
        %\begin{enumerate} \itema blabla \item ss             
        %\end{enumerate}
        \item text
        \item text
    
    \end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

where the `\def` commands are from a post in this forum.

[hide a certain item and remove the left empty line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100995/hide-a-certain-item-and-remove-the-left-empty-line)

My problem now is if I want to open a new enumerate environment in the `\itema`, it fails if the boolean is true and the item should be hidden.

Comment: Could you link to the "post in this forum" where you got the definitions? I did some searching but I was unable to find the post.

Comment: I've updated the post with the link.

Comment: How set are you on your current macro use? It would be difficult to guess what forms part of `\itema` if you don't have a good idea of what follows it. However, using an interface of the form `\itema{...}` would be easy to implement.

Comment: It must have exactly this shape. ``/itema{}`` would unfortunately not work for me.